# Why is my empty Avalonia app using 100% CPU?

Tags: c#, linux, debian, avalonia

I am using AvaloniaUI framework to build an application that I will run on Debian, even the empty application with no controls uses 100% of my CPU.

The build is installed on a Raspberry Pi 7” Touchscreen.

I'm using Avalonia version 0.10.3, I tried older versions but no luck.

This is the git to my (empty) project: https://github.com/pedromambe/MyAvaloniaApp

["top" command showing the 100% CPU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEDZ2.png)

Comment: Related: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5785

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.